# MYSQL Query to make the values as duplicates and remove duplicates from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 692256 number of rows ,which has data similar to below

```
customer_type_id     data             

1                    G.M (1) 
1                    GM (1)
1                    FORD (K.G)
1                    FORD(K.G)
1                    Honda

2                    GM (1)
2                    OTHER
2                    OTHER2
```

in the above case I have to remove duplicates based on **customer_type_id** and **data** columns. 
and the duplicates are not exactly duplicates . For example first two records are duplicates and the next two records are also duplicates . There could be some space or period or braces in data . So To get the duplicates, I have to run the below functions on **data** column

```
trim( replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(data,'.',''),'(',''),')',''),' ','') ,' ','')  )
```

Now I want to remove one of the rows from the above case and keep the formatting of the other row .

In the above case I want to get

```
customer_type_id     Data             

    1                    G.M (1) 
    1                    FORD(K.G)
    1                    Honda

    2                    GM (1)
    2                    OTHER
    2                    OTHER2
```

In fact any record of the duplicate value will be fine . But should not be like below ( in the below case data column value spaces and braces are removed from the existing value)

```
 customer_type_id     Data             

    1                    GM1 
    1                    FORDKG
    1                    Honda

    2                    GM (1)
    2                    OTHER
    2                    OTHER2
```

any help on this ?

Thanks  a lot

Regards

Kiran

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(id), artist FROM news` a example

Comment: Thanks for your response , Here in this I can not use distinct .. Because If I use distinct on the formatted data , I loose the real record

Comment: Value is not exactly duplicates .. Please check my example I have given above .. I have to remove some characters to make them duplicates

Comment: Hi Zohaib , Thanks for your response . I am sorry there is no , But sure If we want I can add another column as primary key and make it as auto increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an AutoIncrement Key "ID"

```
delete 
from table
where table.ID NOT IN (
            select MAX(ID)
            from table
            group by customer_id, your_function(data) )
```

I guess it should work, please check/confirm syntax, I am not sure about that. Idea is to delete all the records except one distinct combination.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful quick solution . I am running it . Taking time ... Subquery is pretty fast .. But the NOT IN is taking time ..

Comment: Thanks again , I crated a temporary table for the above subquery , created index on it and used not exists . The query ran pretty fast and removed the unwanted records .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use LIKE in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data LIKE "%G%M%1%"
```

Where the % stands for litterally anything (nothing, a space, a character, etc).

I'm not sure this will be reliable though, as the above would also match "Grand Master 7331", but if you're sure those kinds of collisions would not happen it might work.

Comment: I am sorry this won't help .. Thanks for your response